# Building a Docker Image a little more quickly

Tags: r, docker, containers

I plan on using a service to receive and grade student code submissions for a class I'll be teaching next semester.

For each assignment (there are many) a shell script runs to build a Docker image. I upload a zip file to the website, and among all the compressed files, there is this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# these lines install R on the  virtual machine
apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev
apt-get install -y r-base

# these lines install the packages that is needed both
# 1. the student code 
# 2. the autograding code

# Note that 
# a. devtools is for install_github This is temporary and will be changed once the updates to gradeR have made it to CRAN.
Rscript -e "install.packages('devtools')" 
Rscript -e "library(devtools); install_github('tbrown122387/gradeR')"

# These are packages that many students in the class will use
Rscript -e "install.packages('tidyverse')" 
Rscript -e "install.packages('stringr')"
```

The problem though is that this takes about 20 minutes. How do I speed this up? I'm totally new to Docker containers.

Comment: One edit is to add `--no-install-recommends` to apt-get install. This will ensure only the required dependencies are installed.

Comment: I am voting to reopen. This question does not need debugging details because there is nothing to debug. This is working code. The problem is that it’s slow.

Comment: @Taylor doesn't make your question more a candidate for an answer. In the current situation and state of your question, only you can pinpoint the exact line taking that much time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'd suggest building a base image containing all of the tools and packages that you think you'll need. There's no need to be picky, because you only need to do this once. That's kind of the whole point of Docker -- portability and reuse.

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev r-base

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('tidyverse')" 
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('stringr')" 
...
```

Build that image and tag it as `grader:1.0.0` or whatever.

Then, when it's time to grade, just mount the assignments and grading code using the `-v, --volume` option to `docker run`. You don't need to alter the container to make files accessible within it.

```
docker run \
  --rm \
  -it \
  -v /path/to/assignments:/data/assignments \
  -v /path/to/autograder:/data/autograder \
  grader:1.0.0 \
  /bin/bash
```

If at some point you need to add some packages, you can rebuild it by modifying the original Dockerfile or extend it by using it as the base of your next image:

```
FROM grader:1.0.0

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y the-package-i-forgot
```

Build it, tag it.

Comment: Mhm depending on the host OS, this could do worst than good. Volumes on Mac and Windows have a quiet long history of slowness

Answer (score 3):

Use [rocker/tidyverse](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/tidyverse/) image from Docker Hub instead of whatever image you're using.

First:

```
docker pull rocker/tidyverse
```

Then add this line:

```
FROM rocker/verse
```